# Resource not found for the segment deviceUpdateStates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We want to receive certain update statuses from our device that are intune managed, before we used this query:
GET /deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/{deviceConfigurationId}/microsoft.graph.windowsUpdateForBusinessConfiguration/deviceUpdateStates

However since a month or two it does not work anymore, the documentation or changelogs does not mention anything about the functionality being removed or moved.

The error I receive is:
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Resource not found for the segment 'deviceUpdateStates'.",

It doesn't seem we are doing anything wrong according to the documentation

This is the link to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-shared-windowsupdatestate-list?view=graph-rest-beta

I tried using powershell invoke-restmethod and graph explorer using this url:
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/25cd38f5-5d0f-4976-8f47-44b7d7c725ab/microsoft.graph.windowsUpdateForBusinessConfiguration/deviceUpdateStates

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Intune support eventually confirmed that the /deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/{deviceConfigurationId}/microsoft.graph.windowsUpdateForBusinessConfiguration/deviceUpdateStates endpoint won't be supported anymore.

I worked round my issue by using the generic deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/{deviceConfigurationId}/deviceStatuses endpoint instead. This won't give you the current feature / quality versions of the devices (although that is available elsewhere) but it does return a compliance status for each device.

You can also pre-validate your deviceConfigurationId by doing a GET on deviceManagement/deviceConfigurations/{deviceConfigurationId} - If the Id is for an update ring then the "@odata.type" returned will be "#microsoft.graph.windowsUpdateForBusinessConfiguration". There is also the update ring name returned in "displayName".

Alternatively you can also download the Intune "FeatureUpdateDeviceState" report via Graph to see compliance against a feature updates policy. See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/reports-export-graph-apis
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/reports-export-graph-available-reports